# Android Java HttpUrlConnection freezing

Tags: java, android, http, freeze

I suspect I'm running into some issues borne out of threading in my simple Android app.

I have a Activity which does the following:

1. runs a dialog on main thread
2. spins a background thread and hits a PHP script for retreiving data using `DefaultHttpClient` and close this connection. This successfully returns a URL to a picture on the internet
3. open `HttpUrlConnection` called `conn` and try conn.connect
4. app freezes at this point with no error

Not sure what code to put here, I could paste it all but that would be too much so let me know if any more info is needed:

```
/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all Question by making HTTP Request
 */
class LoadAllImages extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
  /**
   * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
   * */
  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    // dialog init'd here
  }

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_question_details, "GET", params);



    // Check your log cat for JSON response
    Log.d("All Questions: ", json.toString());

    try {

        // images found
        // Getting Array of questions
        images = json.getJSONArray(TAG_IMAGES);

        // looping through All questions
        for (int i = 0; i < images.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject c = images.getJSONObject(i);

          // Storing each json item in variable
          String id = c.getString(TAG_IMAGEID);
          String location = c.getString(TAG_IMAGELOCATION);

          URL myFileUrl = null;
          try {
            myFileUrl = new URL(location);
          } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect(); // freezes here
            int length = conn.getContentLength();
            int[] bitmapData = new int[length];
            byte[] bitmapData2 = new byte[length];
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

Comment: on a separate note, you are trying to call openConnection on an object that might be null. you aren't catching a nullpointerexception so that may cause you problems down the road. you should probably move the whole thing into a single try block with 2 catch blocks.

Comment: yea thanks, i planned to tidy it up when i get some working code, for now it can access the php and should be able to access the url/jpg

Comment: are there any logs on the server side that might help?

Comment: no, the php on the server side is called and gives url back to code and the code then moves to the httpurlconnection lines and freezes at conn.connect

Comment: Try run in debug mode to see where it freezes.
You can pause the application when it freezes and check all threads.

Comment: i did, it freezes at conn.connect. not sure what im checking for in the threads. any idea?

Comment: Also, the internet url worked before i implemented threading - as u can see i have hatrdcoded the url and it still doesnt work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove these 2 lines:

```
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.connect(); // freezes here
```

When you do this:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl.openConnection();
int length = conn.getContentLength();
```

You are already connected. Calling `conn.getContentLength()` causes `HttpURLConnection` to make the connection, sends the request and fetches the response. You don't need to explicitly connect. You also don't need to call `setDoInput(true)` since that is the default setting.

Comment: same problem except at next line of code - int length = conn.getContentLength();

Comment: Add debug logging or set a breakpoint in the debugger and see what the value of `myFileUrl` is when you call `myFileUrl.openConnection()`.

Comment: i already did 0- the myfileUrl is correct and i can browse to it :(

Comment: Can you check the server logs and see if the request actually arrives at the server? If not, can you use a network sniffer to see if the HTTP request is sent to the server? It looks like the server isn't responding.

Comment: Please post the contents of `myFileUrl`.

Comment: the php fiel does return the info, thats not an issue, the url is https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS22eoAz4Rx8P6iVyszeKVZp6rNRX_cQdd2JMqOdx4Y1BEdMo6t (cough) so i cant check if a request went to that server but i doubt it

Comment: The device you are testing this on, what version of Android is it running?

Comment: I'm guessing that you are using a shared connection or a pool of connections and that somehow that is broken. You obviously used an HTTP connection to retrieve the JSON data using `jParser.makeHttpRequest()`. Maybe you aren't closing that connection properly to return it to the pool of connections or something like that. Your HTTP request is probably freezing because it is waiting either for a connection from the pool OR waiting to reuse another connection that is already in use. Note: this is just a guess. You can post the code for `jParser.makeHttpRequest()` and maybe that will help.

Comment: This answer is not correct. You are *not* connected until you call `connect()` or `getResponseCode()` or `getOutputStream()` or `getInputStream()`. All that `openConnection()` does is construct the appropriate `URLConnection`-derived class. It doesn't do anything on the network at all. Removing `doInput(true)` is OK because that's the default, not because you are already connected.

Comment: Hi guys, it was my mistake, i was behind a firewall and it looks like this stsops the emulator from connecting to the url i stated. the code didnt error out no matter how long i left it and my prv tetsing before my recent was not behind fw so worked. thanks for all your advice, much appreciated.

Comment: @EJP You are technically correct. Thanks for pointing that out. What I meant was that it isn't necessary to explicitly call `connect()`. I've corrected my answer based on your comment.

Comment: Downvote as the answer is wrong, you are not connected after calling `myFileUrl.openConnection()`. The Java Documentation for `openConnection()` clearly states: *It should be noted that a URLConnection instance does not establish the actual network connection on creation. This will happen only when calling URLConnection.connect().*

Comment: @Mecki You shouldn't downvote unless your actually read the answer. I wrote _"When you do this: <code snippet> You are already connected. Calling conn.getContentLength() causes HttpURLConnection to make the connection, sends the request and fetches the response"_ I never said that calling `openConnection()` actually connects.

Comment: Okay, my bad, but it's still a downvote as your answer is no answer to the actual problem and also not helpful. If `conn.connect();` freezes, then `conn.getContentLength();` will freeze, too, because internally it just calls `connect();` and there it will freeze exactly the way it freezes when you call it. Calling `connect()` explicitly is not required, but it is not forbidden either and removing this line fixes exactly nothing. I know it, because I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

**First of all make sure you added Internet Permission to manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**outside the application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml**

---

### Troubleshooting:

1. Try access the same URL using your browser
2. Check if you are not behind proxy or server is not behind proxy
3. Try pinging the server see and check the latency.
4. Try catching all exceptions:

Change `} catch (IOException e) {` to `} catch (Exception e) {`

---

If all looks good try this code:

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl.openConnection();
conn.setUseCaches(false); 
conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
conn.setDoOutput(true); 
conn.setDoInput(true); 

//conn.connect(); // You are allready connected after openConnection().
```

**If still no luck, try using `HttpClient` & `HttpGet` this way:**

```
final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
final HttpGet conn = new HttpGet(myFileUrl.toString());

HttpResponse response = client.execute(conn);
InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

Comment: Hey @Danpe.Troubleshooting:

Try access the same URL using your browser - yes i can
Check if you are not behind proxy or server is not behind proxy - i am behind a firewall but this didnt affect the code when i was running on ui thread.i thenadded the php code on background thread which worked and then moved my internet url code to that background thread which caused issue
Try pinging the server see and check the latency.
Try catching all exceptions:
Change } catch (IOException e) { to } catch (Exception e) { - testing this now ... :)

Let me know what did you found out.

Comment: IOException e to Exception e -> i get same result, debugger just sits at the conn.connect forever. Dialog UI still spinning

Comment: Try the new snippets i posted, let me know what you get :)

Comment: hey what is the useragent variable? its notdeclared?

Comment: il try to add the following                   System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl.openConnection();
conn.setUseCaches(false);                    conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
conn.setDoOutput(true); 
conn.setDoInput(true);
int length = conn.getContentLength();
int[] bitmapData =new int[length];
byte[] bitmapData2 =new byte[length];
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();                   
bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);                   imView.setImageBitmap(bmImg);

Comment: actually no it freezes on the next line int length = conn.getContentLength();

Comment: trying httpget but no such method for InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream(); - any idea how to inti the inputstream?

Comment: thanks i see where i went wrong for your snippet. The problem still persists though, freezes on HttpResponse response = client.execute(conn);

Comment: Did you add internet permissions to your manifest? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Hi, my mistake, my firewall was blocking me. I thought i tested it before but i must have been on a diff network. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Do you have a firewall on your android? Because if you can surf from your PC to the server, then port 80 on the server isn't close by any firewall..

Comment: Downvote as the answer is wrong, you are not connected after calling `myFileUrl.openConnection()`. The Java Documentation for `openConnection()` clearly states: *It should be noted that a URLConnection instance does not establish the actual network connection on creation. This will happen only when calling URLConnection.connect().*

Answer (score 1):

I'd at least put both connect and read timeout in, e.g.

> ```
>       conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
>       conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
> ```

Comment: That's good advice.  The default timeout values are 0 which means unlimited (wait forever).

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue that drove me crazy to solve. I was already setting the timout params, but the httpurlconnection was hanging on connect() call, or later on getInputStream() if I don't call explicitly connect().

Using a raw thread instead of the asynctask worked for me, without changing anything else...

```
new Thread(() -> task.doInBackground())
```

More a workaround than a solution, but better than nothing.